Cannot update authorization callback URL for X (Twitter) provider in Google Identity Platform
I have encountered a question while attempting to configure Twitter sign-in on the Google Cloud Identity Platform.
According to the documentation provided at https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/twitter, it is mentioned that if a custom domain is configured in the Identity Platform, the redirect URI in the Twitter app configuration can be updated to use the custom domain instead of the default domain:

However, I have been unable to locate any option or setting within the Identity Platform to add or modify the custom domain. The Identity Platform continues to display the default URL and does not provide an option to change it to the desired custom domain:

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide guidance on how to add or modify the custom domain in the Google Cloud Identity Platform. Any insights, suggestions, or workarounds to achieve the desired configuration for Twitter sign-in would be immensely helpful.
Thank you!

Any update on this? Facing the same issue

I don't have much update. I still not sure how to change the url in Google cloud. But I could change the authDomain param when initializing Firebase from Flutter. But for some providers that seems to work and for some it didn't. The behavior is also different in mobile and desktop browser.
